# Setting a welcome channel Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Now there are a lot of tutorials on setting up welcome messages, and sending it once a member joins the guild, but they are only for custom servers, because look:

```
const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let fontSize = 70;

    do {
        ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
    } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);

    return ctx.font;
};

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./GANG.jpg');
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.font = '45px Masked Hero Demo';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillText('WELCOME,', canvas.width / 2.4, canvas.height / 3.5);

    ctx.font = '45px Masked Hero Demo';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('WELCOME,', canvas.width / 2.37, canvas.height / 3.6);

    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.57);


    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.47, canvas.height / 1.6);       


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'GANG.jpg');

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}! Make sure to check info at <#743160115833864263>`, attachment);
});
```

At the part where it says welcome, that means any channel matching that name is where the message will send to.

But this would only work using a custom bot, and since I want everyone to use this, depending since they wont use welcome as their welcome channel name. How do I make it that a user sets a welcome channel and then welcome messages will send there?

Sorry, English is my second language.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a variable (ex. `welcomeChannel`) equal to whatever the user wants their welcome channel to be and replace that with your `welcome` section.

Ex.
`let welcomeChannel = "welcome"` and then later on replace

```js
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
```

with

```js
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === welcomeChannel);
```

Everything else will work just fine. If you wanted to create a command though to have the bot prompt it via messaging, that'll require a messageCollector. I'm not certain if that's what you're asking.

Comment: If this was is in any server, will it still be valid? I don't want the server owner editing source code and hosting it himself

Comment: Well in that case you need to set up an interaction between the bot and server owner. For that, I'd recommend using a message command where the server owner can type in the name of the text channel and then the bot can store it into the variable `welcomeChannel` accordingly.